# Triggering submit action on form results in "The backend rejected the commit because it was invalid"

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have to write coffescript code to submit a form using trigger event with invalid data (to test a negative scenario) and to verify the form should be validated before saving.

```
find('.general-settings form').trigger('submit')
```

on running the test result I get this error:

```
The backend rejected the commit because it was invalid
```

console.log says "the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)"

How do I catch/throw an error in coffescript; I have tried several things as mentioned below but nothing has worked out so far.

1)

```
try 
   find('.general-settings form').trigger('submit')
catch e
   console.log e
```

2)

```
expect(find('.general-settings form').trigger('submit')).to.throw('Format validation failed (url must be a valid url)')
```